# How can I say, "What kind of a question is that?" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german, word-choice, usage

For example: “Of course, I'll help you! What kind of a question is that? I'm your brother, for goodness' sake!”

I gleaned some translations from the web but I'd like confirmation from you natives that you would actually use them in a similar context, i.e. you're surprised or upset that someone would even think of asking such a seemingly pointless question.

*Was für eine Frage ist denn das?*

*Was für eine Frage soll das denn sein?*

*Was für eine Frage?*

*Was ist denn das für 'ne dämliche Frage?*

Thank you.

Comment: They‘re all correct, though your question is unclear why you doubt them and what research you did...

Comment: It must be *Was für eine Frage!* as this is an exclamation.

Answer (score 5):

No, these don't work as they are negatively connotated, like *that's out of the question* mostly would be. I would rather recommend

> klar, gar keine Frage --*an elipsis*

adding a confirmative particle for emphasis would turn the other phrases, too, perhaps with a smack of irony.

PS: I see, belatedly, that you had the emphasis already in place. So, yeah, it kind of works. The different variants still set a different ton, especially with "dämlich".

Answer (score 1):

I think your

> Was ist denn das für 'ne dämliche Frage!? / Was für eine Frage!

are well fitting. Or you may say shorter

> Was soll die Frage?

*Natürlich werde ich dir helfen. Was soll die Frage!? Ich bin schließlich dein Bruder.*

The meaning is *'Das ist ja wohl selbstverständlich!'* or *'Wie kommst du überhaupt dazu, mich zu fragen?'*. You have a similar meaning in

> Wie kannst du mich (nur) sowas fragen!?
>
> Wieso fragst du (mich das jetzt)?

According to the tone the speaker may want to say that the answer to the question is obvious or that he is hoping that the addressed person will not doubt about his brotherhood.